# Multiple WHERE. Is there a possibility that a specific WHERE can only be executed in LINQ?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to execute only this for a certain condition

```
somelist.Where(x => x.isTest == true && x.status == request.StatusDescription &&
        (x.reqdate >= request.ReferenceDateFrom && x.reqdate <= request.ReferenceDateTo))
```

and this one for anothere condition

```
somelist.Where(x => x.status == request.StatusDescription
       && (x.reqdate >= request.ReferenceDateFrom && x.reqdate <= request.ReferenceDateTo))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
var somelist=somelist.Where(x => x.status == request.StatusDescription
       && (x.reqdate >= request.ReferenceDateFrom && x.reqdate <= request.ReferenceDateTo))


if(condition==true){
somelist = somelist.Where(x => x.isTest == true)
 }
```

Comment: just figured it out. damn i was just a little confused about it yesterday. got the same approach. thanks!